# How would shared memory IPC (and other IPC) work with multiple CPU?

Tags: ipc, shared-memory

I am working on an architecture with 2 CPUs connected only by a shared memory region and some GPIO/IRQs. They are completely separate so they don't share any cache. However the plan is to have both executing out of the same Linux OS image in shared memory. I am wondering how would IPC mechanisms like shared memory, signals, etc. work? Since the two CPUs are executing out of the same RAM, as long as those mechanisms are kept in RAM then I assume when one CPU went to check the state of a shared memory region it would work as long as there were no coherency problems. How would signals (software interrupts) work in this kind of setup? Is it all handled in RAM? Would there be coherency issues?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're talking about an SMP configuration, a la most desktop/low-end server machines with multiple CPUs, then you should never see any coherency issues, although you could face performance issues with large areas of shared memory. For example, if each processor (of set {0, 1}) has, in its cache, some memory line, and processor 0 writes to that line, it will update it's cache. If the memory location is set to marked, it should write-through to that memory location, and the memory controller of the other processor will either re-load or invalidate it's cache of that line.

This is complicated somewhat in contemporary CPUs since each CPU module has its own memory controller and hence its own dedicated memory. So, it is up to the memory controllers inside the chips to negotiate what cache lines are shared and invalidate shared cache lines if they are modified by some processor core. If you want to know the defauls you might read up on the [MESIF protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MESIF_protocol) which is used by Intel Xeon CPUs to maintain cache coherency in multiple processor module systems. **But the bottom line is, in an SMP system, you should never see an incoherent shared memory state - only performance degradation if multiple cores are hammering the same memory region.**

Comment: In my scenario, the CPUs are entirely separate subsystems, they don't share L1 or L2 cache. Physically speaking they are on separate dice communicating through an interposer. I am not a cache/architecture expert so what you say may still apply, but I believe for this reason it would be possible that coherency problems could exist. Read-only (i.e. instructions) should be no problem.

Comment: I understand. Many (most?) SMP system do not share caches. For example, in Nehalem architectures, each core has its own L1 and L2 cache, and each module shares an L3 cache. The memory management unit makes sure that coherence problems do not happen by invalidating shared lines. What system are you running with? Is it SMP?